# Microsoft Graph API getSchedule endpoint for GCC High not working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to hit /getSchedule endpoint for GCC High environment. I am getting error "Resource not found for the segment 'microsoft.graph.getSchedule'".
As per MS [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/deployments#supported-features) Outlook Calendar is supported in Microsoft Cloud for US Government.
Same endpoint works fine against commercial O365 env - graph.microsoft.com
Is this endpoint supposed to work in GCC High env or not? Am I constructing this wrong?

Request:

```html
POST https://graph.microsoft.us/v1.0/me/calendar/microsoft.graph.getSchedule
Prefer:IdType=ImmutableId
SdkVersion:graph-java/v2.8.0
Authorization:Bearer <token removed>
Accept:*/*
Content-Type:application/json
```

Response:

```html
400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/json
request-id: 4235611c-96b4-4e2b-bca7-65d25f803e21
client-request-id: dd79469d-8928-4f9f-bb7f-a21298692cef
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"USGov Texas","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"4","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_1"}}
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Mon, 08 Mar 2021 06:55:32 GMT
Content-Length: 329

{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Resource not found for the segment 'microsoft.graph.getSchedule'.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-03-08T06:55:32",
      "request-id": "4235611c-96b4-4e2b-bca7-65d25f803e21",
      "client-request-id": "dd79469d-8928-4f9f-bb7f-a21298692cef"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is this issue resolved? I seem to have the same issue